# Tinker Tom is a wild eyed maniac who wants to inject me with strange chemicals. Should I let him?

Tags: fallout-4

I've just made contact with the Underground Railroad, and proven my trustworthiness. This means I get access to the <s>secret clubhouse</s> underground <s>lair</s> headquarters! All right!

In the HQ, I met this kind of crazy seeming guy named Tinker Tom, who, although he insists my scans came up clean, also insists that the Institute has placed terrifying nano-robots in my food to spy on... my digestive tract I guess? I dunno. He seems very concerned and agitated about them, although the *actual doctor* on hand insists that there's nothing to worry about and that Tom has just been using too many chems.

Either way, Tom wants to inject me with some kind of weird serum - which apparently contains *battery acid*?

Should I let him do this? What are the consequences of doing so?

Comment: I see nothing wrong with letting the crazy man experiment on you.

Comment: I told him I dosed myself with radiation, and he was satisfied. I never heard anything about it again. Not sure what happens if you agree.

Comment: @DCShannon I played around with the dialog tree, and I know that Deacon likes it if you take the shot, and when you do, you get blurred 'vision' for a moment but I wasn't able to spot any lasting effects. Hence the question.

Comment: This kind of scenario is perfect for quicksaves.  Akin to thumbing pages in a Choose-Your-Own-Adventure book.

Comment: I assume any resulting effects would apply as perk, but its entirely plausible that there could be other consequences that were not immediately noticeable

Answer (score 5):

When you first go into railroad HQ, somebody says to keep him happy cause he's got all the cool stuff.

If you let him give you the shot, he will offer you items that he creates for you because he then 'trusts' you.

Answer (score 2):

Tinker Tom's shot only seems to drain your health (well, it *does* have battery acid in it) and has no real effect or grants any perks as far as I can see. I guess he really is at least partially crazy...

Answer (score 2):

All I know is that the serum drains your health to one punch death and lets Tinker Tom sell you stuff. Deacon likes it, while Danse dislikes it

Answer (score -1):

Yeah, I wondered about this as well. If you haven't already found out yourself, it seems that, aside from dropping your health drastically, it also 'activates' NERD RAGE PERK. (I picked this up from the FALLOUT 4 WIKI). Haven't tried it out yet, but maybe the drastic drop in health is some kind of pointer. Anyway, it didn't kill me and, that which does not kill us...........